# Was there a Cyclopian Society?

Tags: futurama

As Leela was looking for her species she encountered a shapeshifter posing as a cyclops.  Things led to another and the Planet Express Crew went to a planet which held statues and paintings of One-eyed Humanoids.

Was that castle created just for show?  Or was that a real Cyclopian Ruin?

Comment: Did you finish the episode...? It makes itself pretty clear

Comment: You are referring to episode nine of season two 'A Bicyclops Built for Two'. Ben Brocka is right that the ending should make the truth clear. But to really understand the 'Cyclopian' origins see episode two of season four.

Comment: *Hey, and there's even a statue with no eyes!*

Comment: @Ben Brocka I finished the episode but the ending isn't clear.  That ruin could have been there before he came, and he just came to live there.  That episode doesn't state if the ruins are authentic.  Also, in that very episode he was shown as a lazy person, and I seriously doubt that he would go through all the trouble creating paintings and artifacts for 5 castles just to get a wife to clean each castle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely the shown city was a 'real' Cyclopean City. Reason being that there were other almost identical cities made for the other species. More likely Alcazar (the fake Cyclops)  built it for that purpose or there is the possibility that it was an abandon city of a certain species (It could have been Cyclops!).

Answer (score 1):

There is, however, a monster that eats only cyclops which is shown in the "rebirth" episode, which suggests that there are enough cyclops out there to keep said species alive while not dying out as a species of cyclops at the same time. Unless, of course, this cyclops-eater can survive on other things but prefers a cyclops diet.

Answer (score 0):

Considering in the episode "Leela's Homeworld" she was revealed to be the daughter of New- New York sewer mutants who passed her off as an alien so she could have a better life on the surface world, I'm going to argue the ruins on Alcazar's planet were fakes and the Cyclopean society never existed.